# Admin URL for currently running Celery task

Tags: celery, django-celery

I want to show my admin user a hyperlink to a running celery task.

I use `django_celery_results`, but this only contains rows for completed tasks.

I could write a simple view, but I guess there is already a much more professional solution.

Steps:

- Admin user selects several rows
- My custom admin actino creates an async celery tasks
- I want to show the admin user an hyperlink where he can wait for the result.
- As soon as the result is available a redirect to the django_celery_results admin view should happen.

Which celery add-on could help?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for any add-on I think to accomplish this. You need to subscribe your service to get notified of specific events (task-succeeded, task-received and task-failed come first to mind). Look at [Monitoring](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/monitoring.html) section of Celery documentation. [Real-time processing](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/monitoring.html#real-time-processing) in particular as it gives some example code to start with... This is how Flower works for an example.